# Facebook extending user access token from Windows Forms

Tags: c#, facebook

I have simple method in windows forms app that posts videos on page which I am admin. but GRAPH API USER TOKEN gets expired. how can I extend for more than 2 days? (app will be used for 2 days)

```
        var fb = new FacebookClient("GRAPH API USER TOKEN");

        dynamic x = fb.Get("/me/accounts", null);

        foreach (var item in x.data)
        {
            if (item.id == "PAGEID")
                fb = new FacebookClient(item.access_token);
        }

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.source = new FacebookMediaObject { ContentType = "video/mp4", FileName = VideoId + ".mp4" }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\x\y\" + VideoId + ".mp4"));
        parameters.title = "foo";
        parameters.description = "more foo";

        dynamic result = fb.Post("/PAGEID/videos", parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap that short lived token for an extended token.

This can be done with the following call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
client_id=APP_ID&
client_secret=APP_SECRET&
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Your extended token with be in the response.

Using the C# SDK:

```
var  result = _fb.Post("oauth/access_token",
              new
              {
                 client_id = "APP_ID",
                 client_secret = "APP_SECRET",
                  grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
                  fb_exchange_token= "SHORT_LIVED_TOKEN"
               });
```

Comment: I am using token from graph api explorer. so there is no app involved.

Comment: As far as I am aware, this is the only way to get an extended token.